# Models not showing in admin page (Django on heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku, admin, models

My models.py contains 3 models, but they do not show up in my admin page. I tried registering my models in admin.py, and added admin.autodiscover(), but none of these things seem to make a difference.

I also tried adding my app name to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py but this results in an Application Error (An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.)

Any suggestions on how to fix?

The following is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import numpy as np

class User(models.Model):
"""
Use OAuth to create user account
"""
    videos = models.CategoryFields()
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Video(models.Model):
"""
Contains video, user who created video, create date, video title, average     rating, and all ratings
"""
    # video = models.FileField()... need S3 to store
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user = models.CharField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #ratings = ListField()
    avg_rating = views.getAverageRating()

class Rating(models.Model):
"""
Contains numeric rating, parameter, video which was rated, user ID, response   time 
"""
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.CharField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    response_time = models.TimeField()
```

The following is how my admin page looks right now. "Users" is just all the superusers.

[image: Django admin page]

Thank you!

Comment: You need to do both: add the app in the settings and register your models. Further you need to migrate the database. And I do not think that there is a django.db.models.CategoryFields. If you use django-cateogries you will have to import this from the right module.

Comment: Thanks. I get an application error whenever I add the app to settings. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: You should be running this locally with DEBUG=True before trying to push to heroku, so you will seeb the actual errors. But as the above connect states, there is no models. CategoriesFields so that is at least one cause of your error.

Comment: So I'm now running locally and am getting an improperly configured error, asking me to provide an ENGINE value for my DATABASES from settings.py. I'm using sqlite3, and I don't quite see what the problem is. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you set the database in your settings?
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'filename',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
And then you still need to migrate it.

Comment: What is 'filename'? I've added the engine name, but perhaps my 'NAME' is wrong.